# How to write ffmpeg commands in android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am using **BravoBit dependency** to execute ffmpeg commands in Android. Below is the dependency

```
    implementation 'nl.bravobit:android-ffmpeg:1.1.5'
```

It takes a **String[] commands** to execute the ffmpeg commands. 
But I am not able to figure out how to pass complex commands in the array format. I keep getting invalid arguments error whenever I try to execute my commands.
 Below is one of the commands I am trying to use.

```
String[] cmd = new String[]{"-i", uri,
"-i",overlayUri , "-filter_complex","[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS", "scale=1920x1080[top]","[1:v]loop=-1:size=750","setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB","scale=1920x1080","format=yuva420p", "colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[bottom]"
, "[top][bottom]overlay=shortest=1, format=yuv420p", outputPath};
```

Here **uri,overlayUri** are the input and overlay file path and **outputPath** is the path for output file.

The error that I got

> [NULL @ 0xf6d44e00] Unable to find a suitable output format for '[1:v]loop=-1:size=750'
>       [1:v]loop=-1:size=750: Invalid argument

Comment: All filter spec after `"-filter_complex"` and before  `outputPath` goes as a single string. Don't forget the `;` separators where necessary

Comment: @AlexCohn and how to define codecs ?Will they be separate from filer_complex or with them.

Comment: Which codecs? With very few exceptions, your array will look like ["-xxx", "yyy", "-abc", "def", … , outputPath]

Comment: I got it figured now. Thanks for your previous comments. But for codecs I meant like libvorbis etc and also I am not able to figure out how to use -map commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lot of hit and try methods I got it working with the below format.

```
String[] cmd4 = new String[]{"-i", uri,"-f" ,"lavfi",
"-i","movie="+overlayUri+":loop=200,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB","-filter_complex","[1:v][0:v]scale2ref[ua][b];[ua]setsar=1,format=yuva444p,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[u];[b][u]overlay", outputPath};
```

My aim with the above command was to overlay a video over another video and loop the overlay video to the length of the input video.
What I understood here is that anything starting with `-` is a sub command and should be a index in the command array.